# Comparing two groups with categorical data

Tags: r, chi-squared, categorical

I am a complete newb - I hope I have framed my question well. I will try to clarify anything that is unclear or expressed poorly. Here goes...

I have two groups - New Teachers and Experienced Teachers who have answered survey questions regarding classroom incidents. Their responses have been grouped into the categories of Often/Sometimes and Rarely/Never.

The data for Question 1 look like this:

|  | Oft / Smtimes | Rare / Never | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New | 117 | 64 | 181 |
| Exprnced | 55 | 45 | 100 |
| Total | 172 | 109 | 281 |

For each question with results like this, I want to know if there is a significant difference between the two groups. As the data is all categorical I believe this to be a chi-square test and have put the following code into r to do this:

```
Question1 = matrix ( c(55, 117, 45, 64), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

chisq.test(Question1)
```

Can anyone please advise if this is the correct test and whether the code I have put in r is performing the test appropriately?

Comment: Just an info here, concerning the Chi2 test in R, if you don't specify the option `correct=FALSE` then it will run a Yates correction.

Comment: Fisher’s exact test might be more appropriate

Comment: Your basic method and code are OK. You might get more useful results if you don't group "often" with "sometimes" and don't group "rare" with "never". Instead, convert them to a numeric scale of 1:4 and carry out a Mann-Whitney test instead (ie `wilcox.test`)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to investigate the nuances of each of those options and figure out the best way to ask the question of the data. Greatly appreciated!